# Can't include flutter_blue into my Flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I was trying to import flutter_blue into my project, generated by `flutter create myapp`, but I get an error message directly:

```
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on convert 2.0.1 and flutter_blue 0.4.0 depends on convert ^2.0.2, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with flutter_blue 0.4.0.
And because no versions of flutter_blue match >0.4.0 <0.5.0, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with flutter_blue ^0.4.0. ...
pub get failed (1)
```

I'm using Flutter 0.5.1 (preview release 1).

Are there any workarounds to get it somehow running or any alternative libraries to use Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WorkAround:**

Instead of going with `0.4.0`. Can you with [previous release](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_blue#-versions-tab-) `0.3.3` which is not having this problem.

```
flutter_blue: ^0.3.3
```

**Reason:**

`flutter_blue` updated their dependency [here](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/blob/master/pubspec.yaml#L15) which is not yet updated in `flutter_test`(which is using 2.0.1 of convert). So we have to downgrade `flutter_blue` to use with `flutter`/`flutter_test`

Comment: Thanks, that helped indeed.